# Enabling Telerik gridcheckboxcolumn

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to use a GridCheckboxColumn in a Telerik RadGrid to allow users to select or deselect a particular item.  My problem is that the checkboxes in the column are not cickable.  How do I make them clickable?  Thank you in advance for you help.

```
<Columns> 
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="FMP Item ID" DataField="FMPItemID" UniqueName="FMPItemID" Visible="True"> 
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="IsInclude" DataType="System.Boolean" HeaderText="Included" UniqueName="gcbIsIncluded" AllowSorting="true"> 
    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn> 
</Columns>
```

Comment: Post some code.  This is pretty basic grid functionality that is shown in this Telerik supplied demo:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/column-types/defaultcs.aspx  You must be disabling the checkbox somehow.

Comment: This is how I have the GridCheckBoxColumn set up in my form:  <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn EditFormColumnIndex="1" UniqueName="gcbIncluded" DataField="IsIncluded" HeaderText="Included" HeaderButtonType="None">
                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn> .

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is to update a database based on an ID field that is in the row that the checkbox is located on.  I found a way to amke a clickable checkbox using GridTemplateColumn with a standard ASP.NET Checkbox but I cannot pull out the ID field value from the row it is on.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridcheckboxcolumn

Comment: The documentation is there and the example is very straight forward and works.  If you want help from the community please put in a little more effort and provide a significant amount of code (formatted nicely in the question) so we can help you.  Otherwise don't be surprised when no one answers you.

Comment: You should not need a template column...that's making more work for yourself.  The checkbox column will work perfectly well.  I'd be glad to keep helping if you'd take the time to put a little more effort into providing a complete example of your code that is not working.

Comment: I tried using ctrl-k to format but the system didn't do it.  Thank you.

Comment: I put the code in place and it checks the boxes but they are still not clickable.  Thank you

Comment: <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="FMP Item ID"
                    DataField="FMPItemID" UniqueName="FMPItemID" Visible="True">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
                <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="IsInclude" DataType="System.Boolean" HeaderText="Included" UniqueName="gcbIsIncluded" AllowSorting="true">
                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
            </Columns>

Comment: i tried to use crtl-k and manually indenting the 4 spaces and it still did not format it as code.

Comment: when i try to ctrl-k it goes up the search bar and indenting 4 spaces like the formatting page says to doesn't work either.

Comment: I added to code the the question for you.....The first thing I see is you have an extra template column close tag - definitely want to remove that.  Second, if you look at the demo link I posted above and go through the aspx code, the Telerik demo is using a `<telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn1"></telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>` rather than a checkbox column.  Give that a try!

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/row-selection/defaultcs.aspx